# Is this make behavior expected?

Tags: linux, make, makefile

My folder structure looks like this:

```
.
├── app.c
├── inc
│   ├── butil.h
│   └── libs
│       ├── flagutil.h
│       ├── libflagutil.c
│       └── libflagutil.o
└── Makefile
```

My `Makefile` looks like this:

```
CC = gcc
WARN = -Wall -Wconversion -Wextra -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter
DEBUG = -ggdb -O0

app: ./app.c ./inc/libs/flagutil.h ./inc/butil.h ./inc/libs/libflagutil.o
    $(CC) $(WARN) app.c ./inc/libs/libflagutil.o -o ./app

libflagutil.o: ./inc/libs/libflagutil.c ./inc/libs/flagutil.h 
    $(CC) $(WARN) ./inc/libs/libflagutil.c -c -o ./inc/libs/libflagutil.o

app-debug: ./app.c ./inc/libs/flagutil.h ./inc/butil.h ./inc/libs/libflagutil.o
    $(CC) $(WARN) $(DEBUG) app.c ./inc/libs/libflagutil.o -o ./app
```

I'm slightly confused about its behavior. Let's say I make a critical change in the `./inc/libs/flagutil.h` file. Both `app` and `libflagutil.o` depend on it.

Then, I simply run `make`. Because the main rule `app` depends on `./inc/libs/flagutil.h`, and it's been changed, the line below the rule is executed.

BUT, `libflagutil.o`, which is a dependent of `app` (the main rule) also depends on `./inc/libs/flagutil.h`, and its change could have a critical effect on `libflagutil.o`, which is again, the dependent of `app`.

However, simply running `make` didn't execute the `libflagutil.o` rule, which means that `libflagutil.c` didn't get recompiled, and the `app` executable is linked against the old version of `libflagutil.o`.

This could of course be fixed by explicitly running `make libflagutil.o` after making a change to `/inc/libs/flagutil.h`, and only then running the main rule, but isn't the whole point of `make` to avoid hassles such as this one?

Am I missing something or is this behavior expected?

Comment: What happens if you use the full path to `libflagutil.o` in the target of the second rule?

Comment: I can't see in your `Makefile` section `all` where all dependencies described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the full paths to files in rule targets, otherwise make considers them located in the current directory.

In your case, use

```
./inc/libs/libflagutil.o: ./inc/libs/libflagutil.c ./inc/libs/flagutil.h
```

in the second rule.